# amazon redshift jdbc driver CopyManager.copyIn COPY command syntax

Tags: jdbc, amazon-redshift, bulkinsert

I am looking for an example of what command to pass to the amazon redshift jdbc driver [CopyManager.copyIn](https://github.com/aws/amazon-redshift-jdbc-driver/blob/master/src/main/java/com/amazon/redshift/copy/CopyManager.java) method.  The code comments specifically state that it is intended to accept STDIN for the inbound data that will be copied to the specified redshift table, but I haven't found any examples of what command to pass in (using the `sql` parameter).  I have tried `COPY <target_table_name> CSV DELIMITER ','` , but I am getting the error message `syntax error at or near "CSV"`.

Answer (score 0):

The library CopyManager works well with Postgres (using stdin for the inbound data), but I did not find a way to get around the error encountered with Redshift.  AWS does recommend a best practice for bulk inserts by copying from s3.  `COPY <target_table_name> FROM 's3://<s3_bucket_with_path_and_object>' iam_role 'arn:aws:iam::<iam_role>' CSV DELIMETER ',' NULL AS 'NULL' EMPTYASNULL ignoreheader 1`.  Using stdin to bulkinsert into redshift (especially from an ec2 instance) could easily consume an incredible amount of memory.  Bulk insert using s3 seems to be the best practice.  This does not specifically answer the original question, but the answer to the question may be implied.